# how to add -lxml2 to linker flag?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, web-services, soap

i am doing a application where i am using webservices wsdl2objc to generate the code..

when i build it i am getting so many  errors realated to  libxml and xml,in usageinstructions thy have mentioned

```
Get info on the target and go to the build tab
Add "-lxml2" to the Other Linker Flags property
Add "-I/usr/include/libxml2" to the Other C Flags property
```

but in build tab if i try to add its not getting add i am not able to fix the errors,i am using xcode 4.0.1

plz tel me how to add the -|xml2 and i hv added libxml2 file from sdks/usr/include/libxml2 and also i have added CFNetowrk.frameworks

thank u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the Project(which has blue A icon) in the left pane(also called Navigator). On the righthand side you will see Info, Build settings, etc.

Select the Build Settings there will be a search bar below it.

In the search bar type other Linker Flag. You will see the OtherLinker Flag shown.

Now double click the row you will be prompted a pop up.

Now click the + button and double click the blue area to add.

Same way do it for Other C flag by typing in the search bar

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `-lxml2`, not `-|xml2`. "l" for "library".